# Changing values of the points attribute on hover - SVG - polyline

Tags: css, svg

So I have this `svg` *element*, which is basically a cube:

```css
#rect1 {fill: url(#Gradient1)}
.stop1 {stop-color: black}
.stop2 {stop-color: #5961FF}

#cube {
  transform-origin: 50% 30%;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: translate(-220px, 0);
}

#cube-text {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  fill: red;
  transform: rotate(-30,300, 10);
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  text-shadow:
    -2px 4px 2px rgba(254,254,254,0.5),
    -4px 4px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4),
    -6px 4px 2px rgba(22,44,65,0.62),
    -8px 4px 1px rgba(22,44,65,1);
  opacity: 1;
}

#top {
  transform: translate(0, -300px);
  animation: top 0.5s forwards ease-out 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: url(#blue); 
  z-index: 99;
}

#right {
  transform: translate(300px, 0);
  animation: right 0.5s forwards ease-out 2s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: #152B40; 
  z-index: 99;
}

#left {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  animation: left 0.5s forwards ease-out 3s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: url(#blue-shade); 
  z-index: 99;
}

#left:hover {
  points: "500, 100";
}

@keyframes top {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -300px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    transform: translate(300px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    transform: translate(-300px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-spin {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma|Black+Ops+One|Coda|Codystar|Fugaz+One|IBM+Plex+Mono|Overpass+Mono|PT+Mono|Racing+Sans+One|VT323" rel="stylesheet">

<svg id="cube" height="1000" width="1000">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="blue" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="blue-shade" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4A9BE5"/>   
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text id="cube-text" x="250" y="560">
    <tspan x="414" y="320">Random Text</tspan>
  </text>

  <polyline id="top" points="500,100 250,150 500,220 750,150 500,100" style="fill: #152B40; stroke: ; stroke-width: "/>
  <polyline id="right" points="500,220 500,550 750,400 750,150 500,220" style="fill: #152B40; stroke: #152B40; stroke-width: " />
  <polyline id="left" points="500,550 250,400 250,150   500,220" style="fill: ; stroke: #152B40; stroke-width: 2" />
</svg>
```

When I `:hover` over the `#left` `polyline`, I want to change the *values* of the `points` *attribute*. For some reason I cannot edit that with *CSS* and therefore think `points` isn't a *valid CSS property*.

Comment: In svg2 you'll be [able to edit the `d` property of  a `<path>`](https://jsfiddle.net/q59prvb3/57/), but weirdly enough, not the `points` of a polyline... But browser support for this CSS settable `d` attribute is very weak (IIRC only chrome does support some non-standard syntax). You'd probably be better using SMIL for this.

Comment: thanks im probably just gonna go with SMIL

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no *CSS* *property* that can effect the `points` *attribute* of the `polyline` *element*.

Instead, you can do it with the `onmouseover` *event* and `setAttribute()` *method*, e.g.:

```js
function changeLeft() {
  var left = document.getElementById('left');
  
  left.setAttribute('points','510,560 260,410 260,160 510,230');
}
```

```css
#rect1 {fill: url(#Gradient1)}
.stop1 {stop-color: black}
.stop2 {stop-color: #5961FF}

#cube {
  transform-origin: 50% 30%;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: translate(-220px, 0);
}

#cube-text {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  fill: red;
  transform: rotate(-30, 300, 10);
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  text-shadow:
    -2px 4px 2px rgba(254,254,254,0.5),
    -4px 4px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4),
    -6px 4px 2px rgba(22,44,65,0.62),
    -8px 4px 1px rgba(22,44,65,1);
  opacity: 1;
}


#top {
  transform: translate(0, -300px);
  animation: top 0.5s forwards ease-out 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: url(#blue); 
  z-index: 99;
}

#right {
  transform: translate(300px, 0);
  animation: right 0.5s forwards ease-out 2s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: #152B40; 
  z-index: 99;
}

#left {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  animation: left 0.5s forwards ease-out 3s;
  opacity: 0;
  fill: url(#blue-shade); 
  z-index: 99;
}

/*
#left:hover {
  points: "500, 100";
}
*/

@keyframes top {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -300px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    transform: translate(300px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    transform: translate(-300px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-spin {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma|Black+Ops+One|Coda|Codystar|Fugaz+One|IBM+Plex+Mono|Overpass+Mono|PT+Mono|Racing+Sans+One|VT323" rel="stylesheet">

<svg id="cube" height="1000" width="1000">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="blue" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="blue-shade" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#152B40"/>   
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4A9BE5"/>   
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text id="cube-text" x="250" y="560">
    <tspan x="414" y="320">Random Text</tspan>
  </text>

  <polyline id="top" points="500,100 250,150 500,220 750,150 500,100" style="fill: #152B40; stroke: ; stroke-width: " />
  <polyline id="right" points="500,220 500,550 750,400 750,150 500,220" style="fill: #152B40; stroke: #152B40; stroke-width: " />
  <polyline id="left" points="500,550 250,400 250,150 500,220" style="fill: ; stroke: #152B40; stroke-width: 2" onmouseover="changeLeft();" />
</svg>
```